# How can I get the webcam to work reliably on Firefox using getusermedia?

Tags: html, firefox, webcam, getusermedia, mediadevices

I am designing a website to teach Inuit Sign Language, and it uses the user's camera on multiple pages for the learner to practice signing. It does not stream nor save the signal anywhere: it is only meant to show the user his or her own webcam image. In Mozilla Firefox, the first page that loads the webcam works fine, but in every webpage that uses it after that, the webcam does not work. Reloading the page does nothing (even with CTRL-F5), but closing Firefox altogether and restarting it on the same page makes the camera works... but once again, only for the first page using it.

The bug is somewhat inconsistent, it always happens locally but not always on my host server, and Microsoft Edge works just fine with it. I have no idea what to do to fix this. It's as if Firefox hadn't freed the camera when I left the first webpage or something.

An example webpage can be found here: https://animamundilarp.com/isl_training_tests/practice_inuit_people.html

Click "Next page" twice to reproduce the issue.

Thank you to anybody who can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here is my full code for the page:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>


 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12"><H1>Inuit People</H1></div> <!-- 100% -->
</div> 

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12"><P>Please allow the website to use your webcam for this learning activity. your webcam video is not recorded or sent anywhere on the Internet, and it will only display on your own screen.</P></div> <!-- 100% -->
</div> 

<div class="row">       <!-- This row includes both the video and the webcam video -->
<div class="col-6">     <!-- This contains the video of the inuit sign -->
<video controls  autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="videos/Inuit_people.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
</div>

<div class="col-6">
<video id="media" controls></video>
</div>
</div>

<script>
navigator.getWebcam = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webKitGetUserMedia || navigator.moxGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
//            audio: true,      // I keep this part of the code, but since we do not need audio, I kept it only as a comment, to reduce permissions asked by the website.
            video: true
        })
        .then(function (stream) {
            var video = document.getElementById("media");
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
 
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            logError(e.name + ": " + e.message);
        });
} else {
    navigator.getWebcam({
//            audio: true,      // I keep this part of the code, but since we do not need audio, I kept it only as a comment, to reduce permissions asked by the website.
            video: true
        },
        function (stream) {
            //Display the video stream in the video object
        },
        function () {
            logError("your web cam is not accessible. If you do not have a webcam, you can use a mirror instead to see yourself signing.");
        });
}

</script>


<P><button type="button" class="button_previous" onclick="Change_Page_to_Previous()"><span class="arrow_button">&#8592;</span> Previous</button> <button type="button" class="button_next" onclick="Change_Page_to_Next()">Next page <span class="arrow_button">&#8594;</span></button></P>

<script src="previous_and_next_functions.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I just downloaded Google Chrome to test it, and everything works just fine in Google Chrome also. The issue seems specific to Mozilla Firefox. It's a brand new computer, so I have the latest version of the browser.

Comment: This is a pretty common problem with turning off and on the webcam rapidly.  I'd recommend filing a Firefox bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release the getUserMedia stream when your web page closes. How you do that is a bit of a kludge: you stop all the tracks in the stream.

(Also, all those alternative places to find the getUserMedia function are in the dustbin of history where they belong, so the code can be cleaner.)

Some Javascript code like this, not debugged, should work for you. Notice the unload event handler

```js
const video = document.getElementById("media")
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({ audio:false, video: true })
  .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream
      video.play()

      window.addEventListener("unload", function(event) {
        /* upon unloading do this */
        const tracks = stream.getTracks()
        tracks.forEach(function(track) {
          track.stop()
        })
        video.srcObject = null
        stream = null
      })
    })
  .catch(function (e) {
     logError(e.name + ": " + e.message)
   })
```